# need to find the path for my file (cygwin in Window7)

Tags: unix, path, cygwin

My apology for the "newbie trouble" that I created for myself & apology for my poor command of computer lingo

I am running a Windows 7 laptop and have a big text file (~4Gb) that I need to find certain string.

Most programs in Windows 7 cannot handle the task (file too big to open in any program in the Microsoft suite), so I downloaded cygwin and tried to `grep` the specific string.

The problem is

(a) the 4 Gb file is stored in the desktop of my non-admin account.

(b) I assume cygwin runs in the admin account (although I use the desktop cygwin icon to launch the environment). The reason being that under cygwin, I see the handle `A@Admin-THINK` (running it on a Lenovo Thinkpad laptop)

`grep` the file of interest results in "No such file or directory"

I tried to find the path of the file (`readlink`, `realpath`) but guess the commands were not applicable here?

Also tried `/home/A/file` or `/home/A/desktop/file` but it is clear that my random guess fails.

From windows, the file should be in

```
C:/Users/non_admin/desktop/folder/file
```

What would be the right path of the file to `grep` the string using cygwin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `/cygdrive` to access the Windows filesystem. In your case, try

```
 grep foo /cygdrive/c/Users/non_admin/Desktop/folder/file
```

Answer (score 0):

From windows, you can get the correct file path from the context menu item `Copy as path` into the copy/paste buffer.

In Cygwin mintty, use

`FilePath=<paste>`

where `<paste>` means to use paste from mintty's context menu to make a variable with the value of that path.

Then use

`grep <string> $(cygpath -u "$FilePath")`

to search the file. The `"`'s are in case the file name contains spaces.

HTH